# How can I configure Camel context.xml to execute some methods with multi arguments in java bean on Camel route?

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I want to execute,some methods with multi arguments in java bean on Camel(2.21) route.
their arguments are some elements in body of  Camel message.
the body data type is json,xml,...,etc.
How can I configure CamelContext.xml and code Java class ?

Comment: Can U provide what you have done till now, so that we can help.

Comment: Thank you,Lucifer.I configured a Camel route.First, I set Input file(JSON type) as <from>. Second, I set Bean as <to> . I want to set Bean method using some element in message body,but I don't know how to set the method.Some methods in Java bean have some arguments using every element in json data.

Comment: The thing I really want to do is to specify the argument of the bean method by extracting the data item from the message body.I don't woant to use many setHeader or setProperty component.

Comment: So you need to pass message body directly to bean argument without setting into headers or property. Is it right

Comment: Thank you,Lucifer.That's right.I need to pass message body directly to bean argument without setting into headers or property.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
import org.apache.camel.Body;
import org.apache.camel.Headers;

@Named("demo")
public class MyBean {

    public void processBody(@Body XmlType jaxbBody, @Headers Map<String, Object> params)  {
    }

    public void processBody(@Body InputStream streamBody, @Headers Map<String, Object> params)  {
    }

    public void processBody(@Body String stringBody, @Headers Map<String, Object> params)  {
    }
}
```

Then in the Camel route, post the appropriate body and params:

```
from("direct:demoString")
    .setBody( constant("StringValue") )
    .setHeader("param1", constant(false) )          
    .to("bean://demo?method=processBody")

from("direct:demoJaxb")
    .setBody( constant(myObject) )
    .setHeader("param1", constant(true))
    .setHeader("param2", constant("APPEND"))            
    .to("bean://demo?method=processBody")
```

Comment: Thank you,TacheDeChoco.
I try it,but occurred some error at @Headers params.
This time,what I want to do the following things.

[from : Input data]
JSON data -> {Order:{Customer:{name:xxxx,city:yyyy,country:zzzz}}}

[to : pass to Java bean method]
methodA(String name,String city){....}
methidB(String name,String city,String country){...}

There is also a way to use setHeader, but I think that if you increase the number of items you will be writing a lot of setHeader.

Comment: The error message is below.Syntax error,insert"...Valiable Declaratolr" to complete FormalParameter.

Comment: Have updated my previous post. The type (Map) was missing for @Headers parameter.